# OdbcConnection.GetSchema("TABLES"); not working

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

I am guessing that not all SQL is created equally.  I am diving into the world of DSNs and ODBC drivers in c# and having a bit of a go at it.  I am trying to get all the tables in a database that is defined by a DSN that all I know about it is using a Transoft ODBC driver.  I can connect to it and get back tables using the code:

```
 public void ConnectToData(String dsn)
    {
        System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn =
            new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();

        //conn.ConnectionString = "FIL=MS Access;DSN=" + dsn;
        conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=" + dsn; //dsn equals "Company_Shared"
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
            lstBoxLogs.Items.Add("Connected");                                
            DataTable tableschema = conn.GetSchema("TABLES");
            DataSet set = tableschema.DataSet;  
            // first column name
            for (int i = 0; i < tableschema.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                lstBoxLogs.Items.Add(tableschema.Columns[i].ColumnName);
            }

            lstBoxLogs.Refresh();
            MessageBox.Show(tableschema.Columns.Count + " tables found");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source: " + ex.GetBaseException().Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

It connects fine, and reports tables but not the tables I know I am looking for in the database what comes back is the following:

`TABLE_QUALIFIER`
`TABLE_OWNER`
`TABLE_NAME`
`TABLE_TYPE`
`REMARKS`

I am not sure how to get the actual table names from this information so I can just dump all the data in every table (This is all I want to do).  Is this cause I have to read up on what kind of SQL a transoft database uses and does it render the `conn.GetSchema("TABLES");` call useless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work?

```
using(DataTable tableschema = conn.GetSchema("TABLES"))
{
    // first column name
    foreach(DataRow row in tableschema.Rows)
    {
        lstBoxLogs.Items.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Fixed the code to not use the DataSet.

**EDIT:** Updated the code for future readers to implement the best practice of disposing of the `DataTable`.

Comment: You are the man thanks!  Now I ideally in that foreach I can just do a select * on row["TABLE_NAME"] and get data from each table and write it out to disk. thanks!