# Transoft ODBC sqlReader error: File does not exsist: TableName

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, transoft

I got a question on connecting and getting table names out of a DSN that is apparently a Transoft driver.  This question is here:

[OdbcConnection.GetSchema("TABLES"); not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695349/odbcconnection-getschematables-not-working-on-a-transoft-odbc-driver)

After that answer that worked I could display all the table names.  Now I find out, reading those tables is still not working well.  I get an error:

`Failed to connect to data source: ERROR [HY000][Transoft][TSODBC][usqlsd](log: 5852-142748) File does not exist: APPT`

Where APPT is the tablename it read.  It is a simple piece of code for now:

```
void dumbRead(String tableName)
    {
        OdbcCommand sqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
        // execute sql
        sqlCommand.CommandText =
        "select * from " + tableName; //I even tried with qualifying table name like:
        // "select * from douglas." + tableName; where the douglas. is the account i.e.
        // the table owner I think.
        OdbcDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int fieldCount = sqlReader.FieldCount;
        MessageBox.Show("Field Count: " + fieldCount);
    }
```

But it doesn't work cause for some reason it does not like my select * statement.  It just gives the error stated above.  Is the Transoft USQL a really different beast?

Everything else so far (thanks again to the last post I got an answer on) is working great.

Here is my connect string as per the comment:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDSNName.Text = "Company_Shared";
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectToData(txtDSNName.Text);
    }
    public void ConnectToData(String dsn)
    {

         conn=   new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();

        //conn.ConnectionString = "FIL=MS Access;DSN=" + dsn;
        conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=" + dsn; //dsn equals "Company_Shared"
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
```

Comment: What happens when you run `SELECT * FROM APPT` from your database admin tool?

Comment: I am remote-ing into a clients computer to try to do this, and they have no admin tools.  It is a doctors office and he wants me to get his data from his database, this has been a bear to do.  So is there a free downloadable query database admin tool that doesn't require admin rights to install?

Comment: Is there anyway I can see that in the ODBC setup of windows?  I am not sure and I wasn't even remotely involved in setting up the DB or the system that uses it.

Comment: Possibly based on the driver that it is setup to use.

Comment: All I can see is that it is a Transoft ODBC driver

Comment: I'm not familiar with Transoft. Based on the little bit that I could gather from their website, I would guess that the database is some sort of ISAM/flat file system (they like to use the word 'legacy' a lot). Without more information about the underlying database it's going to be hard to guess at a solution.

Comment: okay maybe a way forword would be to find a database admin tool I can use to just poke at it and see if anything comes up.  I think it has to do with the fact that its using USQL .  I did do a  connection using Excel a while back and that was able to grab most the data from most the tables (excel cause its all that was on the machine :) )

Comment: You may be able to try MS Access. It is DSN aware and should allow you to poke.

Comment: okay ill see if i can get access installed on that machine thanks!

Comment: first of all can you provide the ODBC Connection String..?

Comment: I think I figured out (much later yes I am slow) that the issue had to do with the fact that there database has dependencies on other data sources being set up that it cannot always find.  I suspect this is the issue at least but I am not 100% sure.  I know now that it is a transsoft database connecting to a datasource whose dictionary id defined by .uDD and it is a flat file database with some bindings to cobol something or other?  Their transoft driver is an odbc connection it seems...though on a few of the tables I do see the "file is not found" when trying to do a select * from it.

Comment: Hi Codejoy do you have the connection string you were using, I am trying to connect in a similar way to you but am not able to open a connection. Thanks, Dave.

Comment: I can get that connection string, mine is pretty simple and requires the user name and password to still be written.  I will add it to this post later when I get home and find the code.

Comment: Thanks! Also what version of Transoft Driver were you using?

Comment: that im not sure about.  I will have to double check

Comment: I have the same problem and can't seem to solve it. Did you ever figure out how to query the tables? I'm able to connect to the DB, tried doing it through access, VB.net, usql admin, and the connection to the remote Transoft DB is fine but when I try opening a table it throws the error that the file does not exist. Is there a way to configure the udd files on the client end for a remote connection?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a simple construct like this to build your necessary ODBC commad and connection objects here is an example I have just tested for a simple Insert

```
        OdbcConnection odbcConn = new OdbcConnection(odbcConnString);//your odbc conn String
        odbcConn.Open();
        OdbcTransaction odbcTransStockList;//if you want to use transaction
        using (OdbcCommand odbcmdSelect = new OdbcCommand(strInsertStringAccess, odbcConn))//or if you are using SQL Server I am assuming it's Access
        {
            odbcmdInsert.CommandTimeout = 60;
            odbcTransStockList = odbcConn.BeginTransaction();
            odbcmdInsert.Transaction = odbcTransStockList;
            odbcmdInsert.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            try
            {
                odbcmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                odbcTransStockList.Commit();
            }
            catch (OdbcException odbcEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(odbcEx.Message);

            }
        }
        ((IDisposable)odbcTransStockList).Dispose();
        ((IDisposable)odbcConn).Dispose();
    }
    catch (OdbcException odbcEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(odbcEx.Message);
    }
```